# Unity Trying to get the Hue from a get Pixel using Color.RBGtoHSV but H always returns 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a Unity Game Object and added a script

```
public Texture2D TheTexture;

void Awake()
{

    float H, S, V;
    Color c = TheTexture.GetPixel(4, 4);
    Color.RGBToHSV(c, out H, out S, out V);
    Debug.Log("H: " + H + " S: " + S + " V: " + V);
    Debug.Log(c);
}
```

The Texture is a 10x10 bmp where the entire image is a solid blue surface RGB 0,0,255

When I run this, the H comes up 0.  The C comes up accurately, so I am reading in the image correctly, I believe.

Any idea what I am doing wrong.  Ultimately I am just trying to get the hue of a color from a bitmap

Comment: Sorry about that I accidentally deleted that line of code.  I added it back now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the code you posted you never change any of `H`, `S` and `V` ...

you could use

[`Color.RGBToHSV`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.RGBToHSV.html)

```
void Start()
{
    Color c = TheTexture.GetPixel(4, 4);

    Color.RGBToHSV(c, out var H, out var S, out var V);
    Debug.Log("H: " + H + " S: " + S + " V: " + V);
}
```

---

I saw you added it in your question. But I can't confirm it. **I suspect your pixel has the wrong color.**

For

```
void Start()
{
    Color c = new Color(0, 0, 1, 1);

    Color.RGBToHSV(c, out var H, out var S, out var V);
    
    Debug.Log(c);
    Debug.Log("H: " + H + " S: " + S + " V: " + V);
}
```

I get the correct output:

> RGBA(0.000, 0.000, 1.000, 1.000)
>
> H:0.6666667 S:1 V:1

---

A Hue of `0` would actually be red ...

Comment: I accidentally deleted that line of code during the cut and paste operation, not sure how but I fixed it now..

Comment: I suspect your pixel to be wrong ... for `Color c = new Color(0, 0, 1, 1);` I get `RGBA(0.000, 0.000, 1.000, 1.000)` and `H:0.6666667 S:1 V:1`

Comment: You are correct!  read my answer below.  Thanks for your help and sorry for wasting your time.  I will put my answer in a comment below this and accept your answer

Comment: Turns out the issue was the image itself. I edited the Image but Unity did not accept my edit. After careful review of the C result, I realized I was not getting a Blue Image (RGB 0,0,1) I was getting a red Image, which was my original Image before I edited it. The Hue for Red is... 0. So my code was working the entire time. I ended up deleting my image and uploading a new asset, I attached that to the code and it worked first try. Feel kinda dumb I didn't test this before asking the question, but maybe someone else will benefit from my bonehead move.